# How to make a grade calculator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, while-loop

I am a beginner with python and I am working with this project that will print the result of the students.I am done with nearly everything execpt the percentage.See,in my code,the program will only print the percentage of the last person's marks.I need to make it so that it calculates percentage for everyone individually and then print it at the end.Your help will be much appreciated.Thanks

```
T_marks = 1100
data = {}
while True:
    ask = input("What do you want? ")
    if ask == "y":
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        marks = int(input("Enter marks: "))
        data[name] = marks
        percentage =(marks / T_marks) * 100
    elif ask == "print":
        for (key,value) in data.items():
            print(key,"::",value)
            if percentage > 90:
                print("Passed with A grade")
            elif percentage >= 70 and percentage < 90:
                print("Passed with B grade")
            elif percentage >= 60 and percentage < 70:
                print("Passed with C grade")
            elif percentage >= 50 and percentage < 60:
                print("passed with D Grade")
            else:
                print("You failed")
    else:
        print("Your work has ended")
        break
```

Comment: I notice that nothing is indented after the line `for (key,value) in data.items():`, meaning that loop has no body - thus, the loop will run until it reaches the last item, and then control resumes on the next line. I assume the `key` and `value` variables contain the data from the last item in the list after this happens. So, can you fix your indentation and see if the problem still happens?

Comment: just fixed the indentation... Problem still exists.

Comment: notice that the `elif` condition is only evaluated if the previous one is false. so if you have a `if percentage >= 90` then the second condition on `elif percentage >= 70 and percentage < 90` will always be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compute `percentage` under the `print` case, this should get you what you want:

```
T_marks = 1100
data = {}
while True:
    ask = input("What do you want? ")
    if ask == "y":
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        marks = int(input("Enter marks: "))
        data[name] = marks
    elif ask == "print":
        for (key,value) in data.items():
            # NOTE percentage is under the case when user asks for print
            percentage =(value / T_marks) * 100
            print(key,"::",value)
            if percentage > 90:
                print("Passed with A grade")
            elif percentage >= 70 and percentage < 90:
                print("Passed with B grade")
            elif percentage >= 60 and percentage < 70:
                print("Passed with C grade")
            elif percentage >= 50 and percentage < 60:
                print("passed with D Grade")
            else:
                print("You failed")
    else:
        print("Your work has ended")
        break
```

Also two hints: This code will output `"You failed"` if someone got a grade of 90. You need to set equality at 90 for one of the cases. Also python has simplified comparisons where `and` is not needed. Here is a simplified version, and corrected for case of 90 to get an A grade:

```
T_marks = 1100
data = {}
while True:
    ask = input("What do you want? ")
    if ask == "y":
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        marks = int(input("Enter marks: "))
        data[name] = marks
    elif ask == "print":
        for (key,value) in data.items():
            percentage =(value / T_marks) * 100
            print(key,"::",value)
            if percentage >= 90:
                print("Passed with A grade")
            elif 90 > percentage >= 70:
                print("Passed with B grade")
            elif 70 > percentage >= 60:
                print("Passed with C grade")
            elif 60 > percentage >= 50:
                print("passed with D Grade")
            else:
                print("You failed")
    else:
        print("Your work has ended")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

The `input()` method reads a string, but you cannot convert e. g. `"4 4 4 5"` to int. Method `split()` without arguments creates a list of the words in string as follow:

```
"4 5 5" -> ["4", "5", "5"]
```

Change your input to:

```
marks_string = input("Enter marks: ")
marks = [int(mark) for mark in marks_string.split()]  # convertion to int
```

And change calculate of percentage:

```
percentage =(sum(marks) / T_marks) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation, fixed in edit:

```
T_marks = 1100
data = {}
while True:
    ask = input("What do you want? ")
    if ask == "y":
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        marks = int(input("Enter marks: "))
        data[name] = marks
        percentage =(marks / T_marks) * 100
    elif ask == "print":
        for (key,value) in data.items():
            print(key,"::",value)
            if percentage > 90:
                print("Passed with A grade")
            elif percentage >= 70 and percentage < 90:
                print("Passed with B grade")
            elif percentage >= 60 and percentage < 70:
                print("Passed with C grade")
            elif percentage >= 50 and percentage < 60:
                print("passed with D Grade")
            else:
                print("You failed")
    else:
        print("Your work has ended")
        break

>>> What do you want? y
>>>Enter your name: Alex
>>>Enter marks: 12
>>>What do you want? y
>>>Enter your name: Michael
>>>Enter marks: 22
>>>What do you want? print
>>>Alex :: 12
>>>You failed
>>>Michael :: 22
>>>You failed
>>>What do you want?
```